# AWS CDK: Property 'policy' does not exist on type 'IKey': TypeScript

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-iam-policy

I'm creating an app in AWS CDK that has a KMS IKey with an IAM policy with `PolicyStatement`s attached. My code doesn't attach them to the `PolicyDocument`, however when it comes back to me, it has two `PolicyStatement`s that are effectively the same with one distinction, the principal.

In one, the principal is defined, and the other is  `{}`. AWS's method `hasPrincipal` returns true for either, but when I go to `cdk deploy` it won't accept the empty object one. I tried removing the principal entirely from the `PolicyStatement`, but it didn't like that either.

I would like to delete the offending `PolicyStatement` since all other parameters are the same between the two. But I need to get into the iKey's list of policy statements in the `PolicyDocument`.

When I write my code to get into the IKey defined as:

```js
var secretsKmsKey: IKey = generateEnvKMSKey(scope)
```

with the following:

```js
secretsKmsKey.policy['statements']

// or

secretsKmsKey['policy']['statements']
```

In my debugger, it exists and I can do whatever I'd like with the iKey `PolicyDocument`. However, when I go to transpile I get:

```bash
Property 'policy' does not exist on type 'IKey'.
26   removeKmsEmptyPrincipalPolicy(secretsKmsKey['policy']['statements'])
```

[debugger showing policy property exists on IKey object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO5bn.png)

How do I get into the `IKey.policy` to work with it? Documentation and transpiler says it's not there, debugger says it is.

```bash
aws: aws-cli/2.12.0 Python/3.11.4 Darwin/22.5.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off
cdk: 2.83.1 (build 006b542)
constructs: 10.1.31
typeScript: Version 4.3.2
node: v16.18.1
npm: 8.19.4
```

Tried accessing two different ways with the following:

```js
secretsKmsKey.policy['statements']

// or

secretsKmsKey['policy']['statements']
```

Both worked in the debugger, not in the transpile.

Also tried deleting the principal from the PolicyStatement.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `IKey` is an interface in Typescript and this interface does not have `policy` field defined, so Typescript is complaining. The fact that in reality your variable is instance of `Key` class implementing this interface is not known to TypeScript. You can cast it to `Key` if you want to workaround Typescript. Alternatively, you can change your method to return `Key` instead of `IKey` to keep it clean.